# How to override model in my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

i m using engine ...  i want to override a user model from engine to my app...

please tell me how to do

Model in my local app looks like below

```
 require_dependency EngineName::Engine.root.join('app','models','Model name').to_s
  module EngineName
   class Model < EngineName::ModelName

    def method name
      SUPER
    end
  end
end
```

i am getting error like superclass mismatch for class ModelName,

please give me some sugestion

Comment: look at the official tutotial [Overriding Models and Controllers](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#overriding-models-and-controllers) all the suggestions and exmples are there : For simple class modifications use `Class#class_eval`, and for complex class modifications, consider using `ActiveSupport::Concern`.

Comment: thanks its help me lots but i m unable to use super method from my local app

Comment: EngineName::Engine.root.join('app','models','Model name') why Model<space>Name? Is it your typing error?paste your real code so that i can have a look.and  make it ModelName

Comment: require_dependency Cb::Engine.root.join('app','models','cb','user').to_s

Comment: def api_create_user
         super.api_create_user

     end